# Splitting a file using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Need some help on regex stuff for my assignment.I have to split a multi line text on the basis of content divider

> -------- Original Message --------

Scenario is the content divider can have **any number of "-" character** followed by **any number of space** and **then the text "Original Message"** will come which is again followed by **any number of "-" character**.

Any help is will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\-+\s*Original Message\s*\-+$
```

It means:

```
^                    Start of the string
\-+                  One or more dashes
\s*                  Zero or more whitespace characters
Original Message     
\s*                  Zero or more whitespace characters
\-+                  One or more dashes
$                    End of the string
```

This is a little different than your request as you stated it, but I think it's what you're looking for (specifically, you didn't mention the whitespace characters between "Message" and the second set of dashes).

Here's this RegEx in action:

http://regexr.com?36e1k

Comment: You should add the anchors in your regexr demo and mention that the regex will work properly only in the multiline flag is active.

Comment: I don't think you need to escape `-`

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex below (set **RegexOptions.Multiline** )

```
^[-]*[ ]*Original[ ]{1}Message[ ]*[-]*[\r\n]*[a-zA-Z\r\n ]*
```

To explain,consider if the sample file contains the following text,

> --------------------------------- Original Message----------------------------
>   Some Text
>   Some Text
>   Some Text
>   Some Text
>
> --------------------------------- Original Message----------------------------
>   Some Other Text
>   Some Other Text
>   Some Other Text
>   Some Other Text

The there will be two matches.

- **First Match :**

> --------------------------------- Original Message----------------------------
>   Some Text
>   Some Text
>   Some Text
>   Some Text

- **Second Match :**

> --------------------------------- Original Message----------------------------
>   Some Other Text
>   Some Other Text
>   Some Other Text
>   Some Other Text

Regex in action [here](http://ideone.com/E8eY9H).

Sample [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/67e6iv6w8wpy55y/Text%20Splitter.7z).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[-]+[' ']*Original[' ']Message[-]+$
```

you can validate this regex pattern at http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

The above regex is valid for:
------------Matches-----------
-Original Message-
------------Original Message-
-----        Original Message-
If you want any space after Message and before '-' then :

```
^[-]+[' ']*Original[' ']Message[' ']*[-]+$
```

If space between Original and Message is optional then :

```
^[-]+[' ']*Original[' ']*Message[' ']*[-]+$
```

If space between Original and Message is optional or only one space is alowed then :

```
^[-]+[' ']*Original[' ']{0,1}Message[' ']*[-]+$
```

You can frame your own pattern by modifing this regex and test at http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html